# Count matches of two elements on corresponding index positions in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays where one contains integers and the other words. It can look like this with arrays with 4 elements;

```
arr1 = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cow']
arr2 = [0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Further I have created indexing for all possible pairs:

```
pairs = []
for i in range(4) :
    for j in range(i+1, 4) :
        pairs.append((i, j))
pairs = np.array(pairs)

### Outputs ###
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

I now want to check, for both of my arrays, if the two elements corresponding to the index of the unordered pairs are equal for both of the arrays, and get the count of how many.

For the above example with arr1 & arr2 I'd want;

```
arr1[pairs]# [['cat' 'cat']
 ['cat' 'dog']
 ['cat' 'cow']
 ['cat' 'dog']
 ['cat' 'cow']
 ['dog' 'cow']]

# First inner array ['cat', 'cat'] is matching

arr2[pairs] # [[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 2]]

# First inner array [0 0] is matching
# So I'd want 
match_count = equal(arr1[pairs], arr2[pairs]) = 1
```

So for each possible pairing, if the two elements on the corresponding index are matching in both of the arrays, I want the total number of such matches.

I'd figure I could do something like below to check if an inner array is a match, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the dimensions of the arrays and with the conditions I've mentioned.

```
inner_arr2 = arr2[pairs][0]
print(np.all(inner_arr2 == inner_arr2[0])) # True
```

In my provided example there was N=4 elements, this will be much greater (N=500 & N=1000) so I'm hoping there's some numpy way to deal with this so I don't have to loop over all possible pairs.

Comment: For arr1[pairs] and arr2[pairs], try comparing their own 1st column to their own 2nd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the columns of each array's pairs, and then simply get where there are both a match (`True`) with a `logical_and` operation. You can get the count afterwards with `count_nonzero()` or `sum()`.

```
np.count_nonzero(
    np.logical_and(
        arr1[pairs][:, 0] == arr1[pairs][:, 1],
        arr2[pairs][:, 0] == arr2[pairs][:, 1]
    )
)
```